# NSUserDefaults Create/Call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to use In-App purchase. Please, help me with NSUserDefaults.

I have:

```
free = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Beer", @"Ice-Cream", nil];


paid = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Beer", @"Ice-Cream", @"Pizza", @"Hot-dog", @"Candy", nil];
```

Now, if user successful purchased my product, i have this code:

```
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isProUpgradePurchased" ];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

As default, my UITableView, loads FREE NSArray, how can I creat a NSUserDefaults and call my UITableView to load PAID NSArrary.  Thank You in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in tableView delegate method do this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] ObjectforKey:@"isProUpgradePurchased"])
  {
     return [paid count];
  }
  else
  {
     return [free count];
  }
}
```

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
   ..............
   if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] ObjectforKey:@"isProUpgradePurchased"])
  {
     cell.titleLabel.text = [paid ObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  }
  else
  {
     cell.titleLabel.text = [free ObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  }
}
```

Comment: ... And in every other method, use paid instead of free. If not, this'll crash when paid. See my amswer how to implement this simply and elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *dataArr;

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isProUpgradePurchased"]) {
    // load paid array
    dataArr = paid;
} else {
    // load free array
    dataArr = free;
}

[tableView reloadData];
```

and use `dataArr` when implementing your table view data source methods, don't use the free and paid arrays directly.